# get data related with yii2 on controller

Tags: jquery, json, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have data like this :

**Table feedback**, with entity : `id_feedback (primary_key) , id_user (foreign key), feedback`.
**Table user**, with entity : `id_user (primary_key), user_name`.

User has many feedback, feedback has one user.

I create json in `app/controller/feedback`.

```
public function actionGetReplayFeedback($ID_KOMENTAR)
{
    $replay = Feedback::find()->where('REPLAY_TO_ID = '. $ID_KOMENTAR)->all();
    echo Json::encode($replay);
}
```

I get the json but i didn't get the `username`. How can I get the `username`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply try :

```
public function actionGetReplayFeedback($ID_KOMENTAR)
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return Feedback::find()->with(['user'])->where(['REPLAY_TO_ID'=>$ID_KOMENTAR])->asArray()->all();
}
```

Read more :

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#response-body

Comment: i got an error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: i still didnt get the username

Answer (score 1):

soju is right and if you want to select only some columns (so not all columns of the models feedback and user is returned) you modify the select to something like this

```
$items = \app\models\Feedback::find()
->with(['user' => function($q) {
    $q->select(['id_user', 'username']);
}])
->select(['id_feedback', 'feedback'])
->where(['REPLAY_TO_ID'=>$ID_KOMENTAR])
->asArray()
->all();
```